# Wrapper Methods for feature selection (Machine Learning) In Scikit Learn

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am trying to decide between scikit learn and the weka data mining tool for my machine learning project. However I realized the need for feature selection. I would like to know if scikit learn has wrapper methods for feature selection.

Answer (score 6):

scikit-learn supports [Recursive Feature Elimination](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#recursive-feature-elimination) (RFE), which is a wrapper method for feature selection.

[mlxtend](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/), a separate Python library that is designed to work well with scikit-learn, also provides a [Sequential Feature Selector](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/feature_selection/SequentialFeatureSelector/) (SFS) that works a bit differently:

> RFE is computationally less complex using the feature's weight coefficients (e.g., linear models) or feature importances (tree-based algorithms) to eliminate features recursively, whereas SFSs eliminate (or add) features based on a user-defined classifier/regression performance metric.